# Why is mut not required in an outer function's parameter, though it is required in an inner closure?

Tags: rust

I'm looking at some macro-generated code:

```rust
fn add_iter_exp<'a, I>(int_iter: I, accum: i32) -> i32 // mut not needed here
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a i32>,
{
    tailcall::trampoline::run(
        #[inline(always)]
        |(mut int_iter, accum)| {
            (tailcall::trampoline::Finish({
                match int_iter.next() {
                    Some(i) => return (tailcall::trampoline::Recurse((int_iter, accum + i))),
                    None => accum,
                }
            }))
        },
        (int_iter, accum),
    )
}
```

I'm somewhat familiar with the macro code itself, having worked on it a bit. However, apparently the `int_iter` parameter to `add_iter_exp` does not have to be `mut` itself, though it does need to be in the shown closure (just as shown). I'm curious why this is - my understanding of mutation propagation must be lacking. Is there any circumstance where an argument to the closure would require the corresponding argument in `add_iter_exp` to need to be `mut`? As noted in the title, we can NOT get rid of the `mut` in `|(mut int_iter, accum)|`.

`run`'s signature is:

```rust
pub fn run<StepFn, Input, Output>(step: StepFn, mut input: Input) -> Output
where
    StepFn: Fn(Input) -> Next<Input, Output>,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> … apparently the `int_iter` parameter to `add_iter_exp` does not have to be `mut` itself, though it does need to be in the shown closure (just as shown). I'm curious why this is - my understanding of mutation propagation must be lacking.

1. `add_iter_exp` takes `int_iter` of type `I` by value — it is *moved* into the function.
2. `add_iter_exp` constructs the tuple `(int_iter, accum)`, thus *moving* `int_iter` into the tuple.
3. `add_iter_exp` passes the tuple to `tailcall::trampoline::run` — the tuple is again *moved.*
4. `tailcall::trampoline::run` stores the passed tuple in `input`, which is declared mutable. Therefore, it owns and can mutate the tuple, which owns the value which was known as `int_iter` inside `add_iter_exp`.
5. You didn't give the body of `run`, but it presumably causes `step` to be called with the tuple (whose type is known as `Input` here). Again, this is a transfer of ownership from `run` (or whatever machinery it invokes) to the closure.
6. The closure destructures the tuple, *moving* `int_iter` and `accum` out of it. `int_iter` is declared mutable, so the closure is free to mutate it.

When a value is *owned,* there is no requirement that the entire chain of custody up till then was marked mutable. It is only when you are *borrowing* that this sort of property exists: you cannot, given an `&` reference, obtain an `&mut` reference to the same referent.

The `mut` in `&mut` is different from the `mut` that precedes a variable name being bound (in a pattern). The latter affects only what can be done with *that variable* and is irrelevant after the value is moved or copied out of that variable.

> Is there any circumstance where an argument to the closure would require the corresponding argument in `add_iter_exp` to need to be `mut`?

The correspondence means that the closure's arguments *shadow* `add_iter_exp`'s arguments — the latter *cannot be affected* by what the closure does because they are not mentionable.  If the closure used different names, then it could try to access `add_iter_exp`'s arguments as “closed over” variables. In that case, it would matter whether or not they were declared `mut`. But, that would also require that those values hadn't been moved away in step 2 of my list, and also that the closure didn't outlive the stack frame of `add_iter_exp` (which is probably not the situation in this context, given that we're talking about things like tail call trampolines).